# Publication of Marketplace Application for Organization Unit Service Account Access

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

We've a request to build a Marketplace SDK app which would implicitly grant service account access to any organizational unit it was installed within. We've been told this is a common practice, but the app was rejected in the review process as we link to an informational page for the Google Chrome extension this app supports.

Other Marketplace apps appear to do this, notably RingCentral for Google Calendar.

Does anyone have advice regarding how to characterize this app so it passes the review process?

Thank you,
Ben

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an appstore/marketplace question and not a programming question. Contact the customer support department of the appropriate vendor for questions about their requirements.

Comment: @KenWhite The was the forum i was directed to by customer support. Do you have alternate contact info?

Comment: All questions must meet this site's guidelines, and off-site vendors do not set this site's guidelines. It doesn't matter where they directed you; go back to them and explain that your question does not meet the guidelines of this site because it is not a programming related question. You can refer them to [Why we're not Customer Service for your favorite company?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/62576)

Comment: Ben, please send an email explaining your case to gsm-reviews-team@google.com and add me, atamalet@google.com, in copy.

Comment: In the end it was necessary to develop a small JavaScript client app which demonstrated use of the requested scopes. My advice from our experience is to read https://developers.google.com/gsuite/marketplace/requirements carefully (do not use existing marketplace apps as a guide), plan time to work through the app review process, and start as early as possible in the software development lifecycle.